# How to "prepend" repo history in git

Tags: git, github

I have starter a repo by checking out a public repo and committing the code, instead of starting of a fork - so my "fork" doesn't include the history of the original (actually the reason for this is that this is kinda of a framework and this were the instructions). Now I realised I want to still get bugfixes from upstream.

How do I start a fork and apply my history on top of it? I know how to fork to a new repo, revert to a certain commit (where my history started) but I'm not very sure how to apply my history on top of it. Then I know how to fetch updates and merge them.

It's all on github (mine and the original repo), if that could help.

Comment: You're looking for `git rebase`.

Comment: I know `git rebase` very well. But if the source is repo A and my changes are in repo B (which doesn't include the history of repo A), I'm not sure how I'd use rebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git pull` to pull all of the commits in repo B into a new branch in repo A, then use `git rebase` to replay that branch on top of an existing branch.

Comment: I tried that, but it wouldn't work. As my repo's first commit is the original's history late commit. So trying to replay the whole history of the original repo on top of mine fails.

Comment: @ddinchev: Do `git rebase -i newBranch` and delete the first commit.  Or do `git cherry-pick` with a commit range that excludes the first commit.

Comment: You mean to replay my history, without the first commit, on top of the new branch that includes the whole history of the original one? Hmmm, that could work!